# Mark task exception as handled

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, aggregateexception

How can I mark an exception thrown in a task as handled. The problem is when I call the `Wait()` method of a task, it will throw an `AggregateException` even when I have already handled the `AggregateException` a long time ago.
The following code snippet shows the problem I want to solve. I my original code I handle the `AggregateException` in one part of my code and I call the `Wait()` method in another part of my code. But the problem is the same.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = null;

    try
    {
        task = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task started");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("my test exception");
        });

        task.ContinueWith(t => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task faulted");
            AggregateException ae = t.Exception;
            ae.Flatten().Handle(ex =>
            {
                if (typeof(InvalidOperationException) == ex.GetType())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("InvalidOperationException handled --> " + ex.Message);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            });
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        task.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AggregateException thrown again!!! Why???");
        ae.Flatten().Handle(ex =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return true;
            });              
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.Read();
}
```

The code above produces the following output:

- Task started
- Task faulted
- InvalidOperationException handled --> my test exception
- AggregateException thrown again!!! Why???
- my test exception
- Finished

Comment: It seems as if there is no way to mark an exception as handled. Calling the wait method will always throw the AggregateException if the tasks state is faulted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a faulted task is `Wait`ed the exception is rethrown. It would be unreliable design if an exception would be thrown just sometimes.

But, if you're adding a continuation that handles the exception and you don't want it thrown again then simply don't `Wait` that task again. `Wait` the continuation task (that you're currently not using) instead. It would only complete after the original task completed and if you need the result simply have the continuation return that. This way the exception would be handled only once:

```
Task continuation = task.ContinueWith(t => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task faulted");
    AggregateException ae = t.Exception;
    ae.Flatten().Handle(ex =>
    {
        if (typeof(InvalidOperationException) == ex.GetType())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("InvalidOperationException handled --> " + ex.Message);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

task.Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
continuation.Wait();
```

Note: That will throw a `TaskCanceledException` when the original task doesn't throw an exception because the continuation is canceled (due to `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`). To avoid that simply remove the flag and check whether `t.IsFaulted`.